# Unexpected error when unit testing nested JNA Structure objects

Tags: java, windows, junit, jna

The following unit test is intended to verify that a nested JNA data structure is properly parsed based on the data that gets passed into the constructor. The unit test properly checks when JNA initializes the 'parent' structure. However, the test fails when testing member variables of a nested structure. I suspect the problem to be that the unit test sets a pointer to a memory location that contains the data for the nested structure. Perhaps the Java Pointer isn't translating one-to-one to how C does it.

I tried placing the WlanBssEntry at the start of WlanBssEntry[] but that didn't provide any different results than how it is currently implemented. When I tried placing it contiguously, I did not call `pointerToMem.setPointer(8, ...)`

This is the unit test:

```java
package com.sevensignal.EyeQAgent.Util.win32.struct;

import com.sevensignal.EyeQAgent.Models.Platform;
import com.sevensignal.EyeQAgent.Util.Utils;
import com.sun.jna.Memory;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.junit.Assume.assumeThat;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Utils.class})
public class WlanBssListTest {

    Pointer pWlanBssList;

    private final static long OFFSET_TO_FIRST_WLAN_BSS_ENTRY = 1024;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        assumeThat(Utils.getPlatform(), equalTo(Platform.WINDOWS));
        pWlanBssList = allocateMemory(65536);
        initWlanBssEntryMemory(pWlanBssList, OFFSET_TO_FIRST_WLAN_BSS_ENTRY, 50);
        initWlanBssListMemory(pWlanBssList, 12, 1, OFFSET_TO_FIRST_WLAN_BSS_ENTRY);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSetTotalSize() {
        WlanBssList subject = new WlanBssList(pWlanBssList);
        assertEquals("should set total size", new WinDef.DWORD(12), subject.dwTotalSize);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSetNumberOfItems() {
        WlanBssList subject = new WlanBssList(pWlanBssList);
        assertEquals("should set number of items", new WinDef.DWORD(1), subject.dwNumberOfItems);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldInitWlanBssEntries() {
        WlanBssList subject = new WlanBssList(pWlanBssList);
        assertEquals("should init WLAN BSS Entries", 1, subject.wlanBssEntries.length);
        assertEquals("should init WLAN BSS Entry data struct", new WinDef.LONG(50), subject.wlanBssEntries[0].uPhyId);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldInitWlanBssEntriesWhenNoEntriesExist() {
        pWlanBssList.setInt(4, 0);
        WlanBssList subject = new WlanBssList(pWlanBssList);
        assertEquals("should init WLAN BSS Entries when no entries exist", 0, subject.wlanBssEntries.length);
    }

    private Pointer allocateMemory(long size) {
        return new Memory(size).share(0);
    }

    private void initWlanBssListMemory(Pointer pointerToMem, int dwTotalSize, int dwNumberOfItems, long offsetToWlanBssEntry) {
        pointerToMem.setInt(0, dwTotalSize);
        pointerToMem.setInt(4, dwNumberOfItems);
        pointerToMem.setPointer(8, pointerToMem.share(offsetToWlanBssEntry));
    }

    private void initWlanBssEntryMemory(Pointer pointerToMem, long offsetToWlanBssEntry, long uPhyId) {
        final int PHY_ID_OFFSET = 40;
        pointerToMem.setLong(offsetToWlanBssEntry + 0, 3);
        pointerToMem.setByte(offsetToWlanBssEntry + 8, (byte)'T');
        pointerToMem.setByte(offsetToWlanBssEntry + 9, (byte)'S');
        pointerToMem.setByte(offsetToWlanBssEntry + 10, (byte)'T');
        pointerToMem.setLong(offsetToWlanBssEntry + PHY_ID_OFFSET, uPhyId);
    }
}
```

This is the WlanBssList class which is the highest level structure:

```java
package com.sevensignal.EyeQAgent.Util.win32.struct;

import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.DWORD;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class WlanBssList extends Structure {

    public DWORD dwTotalSize;
    public DWORD dwNumberOfItems;
    public WlanBssEntry[] wlanBssEntries;

    public static class ByReference extends WlanBssList implements Structure.ByReference
    {
        public ByReference()
        {

        }

        public ByReference(Pointer p)
        {
            super(p);
        }
    }

    public WlanBssList() {
        wlanBssEntries = new WlanBssEntry[1];
    }

    public WlanBssList(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
        dwTotalSize = new DWORD(p.getInt(0));
        dwNumberOfItems = new DWORD(p.getInt(4));
        if(dwNumberOfItems.intValue() > 0) {
            wlanBssEntries = new WlanBssEntry[dwNumberOfItems.intValue()];
            readField("wlanBssEntries");
        } else {
            wlanBssEntries = new WlanBssEntry[0];
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("dwTotalSize", "dwNumberOfItems", "wlanBssEntries");
    }
}
```

And these are the nested structures:

```java
package com.sevensignal.EyeQAgent.Util.win32.struct;

import com.sevensignal.EyeQAgent.Models.InformationElementGetter;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LONG;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.ULONG;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.ULONGLONG;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.USHORT;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WlanBssEntry extends Structure implements InformationElementGetter {

    public DOT11_SSID dot11Ssid;
    public ULONG uPhyId;
    public DOT11_MAC_ADDRESS dot11Bssid;
    public int dot11BssType;
    public int dot11BssPhyType;
    public LONG lRssi;
    public ULONG uLinkQuality;
    public boolean bInRegDomain;
    public USHORT usBeaconPeriod;
    public ULONGLONG ullTimestamp;
    public ULONGLONG ullHostTimestamp;
    public USHORT usCapabilityInformation;
    public ULONG ulChCenterFrequency;
    public WlanRateSet wlanRateSet;
    public ULONG ulIeOffset;
    public ULONG ulIeSize;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder()
    {
        return Arrays.asList("dot11Ssid",
                "uPhyId",
                "dot11Bssid",
                "dot11BssType",
                "dot11BssPhyType",
                "lRssi",
                "uLinkQuality",
                "bInRegDomain",
                "usBeaconPeriod",
                "ullTimestamp",
                "ullHostTimestamp",
                "usCapabilityInformation",
                "ulChCenterFrequency",
                "wlanRateSet",
                "ulIeOffset",
                "ulIeSize");
    }

    public byte[] getInformationElement() {
        return this.getPointer()
                .getByteArray(this.ulIeOffset.intValue(), this.ulIeSize.intValue());
    }
}
```

```java
package com.sevensignal.EyeQAgent.Util.win32.struct;

import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class DOT11_SSID extends Structure
{
    public static class ByReference extends DOT11_SSID implements Structure.ByReference
    {

    }

    public static int DOT11_SSID_MAX_LENGTH = 32;

    /**
     * The length, in bytes, of the ucSSID array.
     */
    public ULONG uSSIDLength;

    /**
     * The SSID. DOT11_SSID_MAX_LENGTH is set to 32.
     */
    public byte[] ucSSID;

    public DOT11_SSID()
    {
        ucSSID = new byte[DOT11_SSID_MAX_LENGTH];
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder()
    {
        return Arrays.asList("uSSIDLength", "ucSSID");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if(uSSIDLength != null) {
            int ssidArrayLength = uSSIDLength.intValue();
            if (ssidArrayLength > DOT11_SSID_MAX_LENGTH) {
                ssidArrayLength = DOT11_SSID_MAX_LENGTH;
            }

            return new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(ucSSID, 0, ssidArrayLength));
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

The results of the unit test are:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: should init WLAN BSS Entry data struct 
Expected :50
Actual   :0
```

The assertion that fails is:

`assertEquals("should init WLAN BSS Entry data struct", new WinDef.LONG(50), subject.wlanBssEntries[0].uPhyId);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   I'm not sure but think your array initialization `wlanBssEntries = new WlanBssEntry[dwNumberOfItems.intValue()];` won't work.  You should do `wlanBssEntries = (new WlanBssEntry()).toArray(dwNumberOfItems.intValue());`.   (Also JNA doesn't support 0 length arrays so the second part of your conditional is impossible: always initialize with at least 1 element.)

Comment: to be more clear, the `new foo[]` structure array only works on the Java side and does not initialize the structure object.  You would have to initialize every individual `foo` in the array (non-contiguous native memory which wouldn't work well as an array parameter) or use `toArray()` to initialize the structures with contiguous native memory.

Comment: I tried `wlanBssEntries = (WlanBssEntry[])(new WlanBssEntry()).toArray(dwNumberOfItems.intValue());`. However, the test still fails. How does `readField("wlanBssEntries")` know where to index the memory of the C structure that contains the `WlanBssEntry[]` data? In other words, I think the problem now is that the data I'm initializing for the `WlanBssEntry` within the unit test is in a location that the `readField` is not using.

Comment: JNA iterates over the fields in your `FieldOrder` list, using reflection to get the mapped class so it knows their native size so it knows the offset.  Are you sure your calculated offsets are correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure my offsets are correct. I've looked over them multiple times. I'm not sure about these things in my unit test:
(1) What value should I use in my unit test `pointerToMem.setPointer(8, <value>)`?
(2) Should I use method `setPointer` or something else?
(3) Where in memory should I init the data for `WlanBssEntry` (see `initWlanBssEntryMemory`)?

Comment: I'll admit I haven't gone through line by line.  You can use `Structure.fieldOffset()` to get what JNA thinks the offset is for your fields and see if that matches up what you're testing.  Generally I wouldn't manually 'set*()` anything, that's part of what JNA does... will look at this a little later.

Comment: I figured it out. I'll post my answer later but wanted to let you know so you don't spend your valuable time. In short, my problem was two fold. First, I did have an offset problem in the data that I was initializing. Second, I didn't place the data I was initializing at the "end" of the WlanBssList (starting at offset 8). Thank you for your help. Your mention of `toArray` helped and having another sounding board was all it took.

Comment: Glad you fixed it and that I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the failing unit test. There were 2 problems when the data was initialized in the allocated memory.

First of all, the offset into the `uPhyId` was off by 4 because I thought the length field of the `dot11Ssid` was 8 rather than 4.

Secondly, the memory for the first `WlanBssEntry` is located at an offset of 8 into the `WlanBssList` structure.

Lastly, I changed how `wlanBssEntries` gets initialized to guarantee that the array of `WlanBssEntry` instances appear contiguously in memory. My unit tests passed even without this change. But per @Daniel Widdis recommendations plus some online documentation I figured it's best to follow recommended procedures. It gets initialized as follows:

`wlanBssEntries = (WlanBssEntry[])(new WlanBssEntry()).toArray(dwNumberOfItems.intValue());`

Here is the code for the passing unit test:

```java
package com.sevensignal.EyeQAgent.Util.win32.struct;

import com.sevensignal.EyeQAgent.Models.Platform;
import com.sevensignal.EyeQAgent.Util.Utils;
import com.sun.jna.Memory;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.junit.Assume.assumeThat;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Utils.class})
public class WlanBssListTest {

    Pointer pWlanBssList;

    private final static long OFFSET_TO_FIRST_WLAN_BSS_ENTRY = 8;
    private final static int PHY_ID_OFFSET = 36;
    private final static int WLAN_BSS_ENTRY_LENGTH = 360;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        assumeThat(Utils.getPlatform(), equalTo(Platform.WINDOWS));
        pWlanBssList = allocateMemory(65536);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSetTotalSize() {
        initWlanBssListMemory(pWlanBssList, 12, 1);
        WlanBssList subject = new WlanBssList(pWlanBssList);
        assertEquals("should set total size", new WinDef.DWORD(12), subject.dwTotalSize);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSetNumberOfItems() {
        initWlanBssListMemory(pWlanBssList, 12, 1);
        WlanBssList subject = new WlanBssList(pWlanBssList);
        assertEquals("should set number of items", new WinDef.DWORD(1), subject.dwNumberOfItems);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldInitWlanBssEntries() {
        initWlanBssListMemory(pWlanBssList, 12, 1);
        WlanBssList subject = new WlanBssList(pWlanBssList);
        assertArrayEquals("should init SSID entry in WLAN BSS Entry data struct",
                new byte[]{
                        (byte)'I', (byte)'D', (byte)'1', (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00
                },
                subject.wlanBssEntries[0].dot11Ssid.ucSSID);
        assertEquals("should init WLAN BSS Entry data struct", new WinDef.LONG(51), subject.wlanBssEntries[0].uPhyId);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldInitTwoWlanBssEntries() {
        initWlanBssListMemory(pWlanBssList, 12, 2);
        WlanBssList subject = new WlanBssList(pWlanBssList);
        assertArrayEquals("should init SSID entry in WLAN BSS Entry data struct",
                new byte[]{
                        (byte)'I', (byte)'D', (byte)'1', (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00
                },
                subject.wlanBssEntries[0].dot11Ssid.ucSSID);
        assertEquals("should init WLAN BSS Entry data struct", new WinDef.LONG(51), subject.wlanBssEntries[0].uPhyId);

        assertArrayEquals("should init SSID entry in WLAN BSS Entry data struct",
                new byte[]{
                        (byte)'I', (byte)'D', (byte)'2', (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00
                },
                subject.wlanBssEntries[1].dot11Ssid.ucSSID);
        assertEquals("should init WLAN BSS Entry data struct", new WinDef.LONG(0xC2), subject.wlanBssEntries[1].uPhyId);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldInitWlanBssEntriesWhenNoEntriesExist() {
        initWlanBssListMemory(pWlanBssList, 12, 0);
        WlanBssList subject = new WlanBssList(pWlanBssList);
        assertEquals("should init WLAN BSS Entries when no entries exist", 0, subject.wlanBssEntries.length);
    }

    private Pointer allocateMemory(long size) {
        return new Memory(size).share(0);
    }

    private void initWlanBssListMemory(Pointer pointerToMem, int dwTotalSize, int dwNumberOfItems) {
        pointerToMem.setInt(0, dwTotalSize);
        pointerToMem.setInt(4, dwNumberOfItems);
        initWlanBssEntryMemory(pointerToMem);
    }

    private void initWlanBssEntryMemory(Pointer pointerToWlanBssEntryMem) {
        pointerToWlanBssEntryMem.setLong(OFFSET_TO_FIRST_WLAN_BSS_ENTRY + 0, 3);
        pointerToWlanBssEntryMem.setByte(OFFSET_TO_FIRST_WLAN_BSS_ENTRY + 4, (byte)'I');
        pointerToWlanBssEntryMem.setByte(OFFSET_TO_FIRST_WLAN_BSS_ENTRY + 5, (byte)'D');
        pointerToWlanBssEntryMem.setByte(OFFSET_TO_FIRST_WLAN_BSS_ENTRY + 6, (byte)'1');
        pointerToWlanBssEntryMem.setMemory(OFFSET_TO_FIRST_WLAN_BSS_ENTRY + 7, 29, (byte)0);
        pointerToWlanBssEntryMem.setLong(OFFSET_TO_FIRST_WLAN_BSS_ENTRY + PHY_ID_OFFSET, 51);

        pointerToWlanBssEntryMem.setLong(OFFSET_TO_FIRST_WLAN_BSS_ENTRY + WLAN_BSS_ENTRY_LENGTH + 0, 3);
        pointerToWlanBssEntryMem.setByte(OFFSET_TO_FIRST_WLAN_BSS_ENTRY + WLAN_BSS_ENTRY_LENGTH + 4, (byte)'I');
        pointerToWlanBssEntryMem.setByte(OFFSET_TO_FIRST_WLAN_BSS_ENTRY + WLAN_BSS_ENTRY_LENGTH + 5, (byte)'D');
        pointerToWlanBssEntryMem.setByte(OFFSET_TO_FIRST_WLAN_BSS_ENTRY + WLAN_BSS_ENTRY_LENGTH + 6, (byte)'2');
        pointerToWlanBssEntryMem.setMemory(OFFSET_TO_FIRST_WLAN_BSS_ENTRY + WLAN_BSS_ENTRY_LENGTH + 7, 29, (byte)0);
        pointerToWlanBssEntryMem.setLong(OFFSET_TO_FIRST_WLAN_BSS_ENTRY + WLAN_BSS_ENTRY_LENGTH + PHY_ID_OFFSET, 0xC2);
    }
}
```